# JQuery Div Slideshow in List Without Plugin

Tags: jquery

I was trying to implement a slideshow using JQuery without using plugin. I have three div in one list, and I want every time I click the next button, the current div will move out and the next div will move in. Unfortunately, when I clicked next button, all three div in the list moved out. Could anyone help me figure that out? I know I may need a loop to track current div, but I tried a lot and still could not find the right solution. I will appreciate any help from you!

Here is my html code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><div>Lucy</div></li>
        <li><div>Karolin</div></li>
        <li><div>Ashley</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="button"><img src="next.png" /></div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

#container{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-top:5%;
}

ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}

ul li div {
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:relative;
}

#button {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:10%;
}
```

This is my JQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentDiv = $('ul li div');
    var currentWidth = currentDiv.height();
    var totalWidth = currentDiv.length * currentWidth;
    $('ul').css({
        width: function(){
            return totalWidth;
        }
    });

    $('#button').click(function(){
        $(currentDiv).animate({
            "margin-left":(-1*currentWidth)}, 1000)
    });


});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that all are animating is because your selector

```
var currentDiv = $('ul li div');
```

you'd need to do something to isolate the index that you are looking to move.  Maybe something like

```
var currentDiv = $('ul li div').eq(1);
```

for moving the div on index 1

Comment: If this answers your question, make sure to mark it correct.  Enjoy your day.